# npx degit could not find commit hash for master

Tags: javascript, authentication, github, svelte, degit

On my Ubuntu 18.04 machine I'm following a [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/) to start a svelte project but I can not authenticate using degit:

```
$ npx degit sveltesj/template ninjapolls
Username for 'https://github.com': myname
Password for 'https://myname@github.com': mypw
! could not fetch remote https://github.com/sveltesj/template
! could not find commit hash for master
```

I'm pretty sure that my credentials are correct because I've just logged in to github with it on browser. So what could be wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: (1) Check if `git` is in your windows path.  More info here: https://github.com/Rich-Harris/degit/issues/37

Comment: I had this same issue...turns out git not install in my pc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a typo in your degit command: `sveltesj` instead of `sveltejs`.

Answer (score 3):

### Dec, 2021 Update:

You need to install **"git"**:

```
sudo apt install git
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install git for degit to work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31016169)

Answer (score 0):

Git was ok. Running behind a corporate proxy got a similar erro:

```
λ npx degit chromaui/intro-storybook-angular-template taskbox
npx: instalou 1 em 2.019s
! could not fetch remote https://github.com/chromaui/intro-storybook-angular-template
! could not find commit hash for HEAD
```

Restarted the local proxy (CNTLM or WinFoom) and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the default branch on the targeted repository provider is changed so:

1- First clear the npm cache by:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

2- Upgrade digit to the latest version:

```
npm install -g degit@latest
```

If none of the above helps check if your git is the latest version or check if you have missed placing it in the environment variable "path",