# npx degit could not find commit hash for HEAD

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, degit

**npx degit sveltejs/template hello-world**

**! could not fetch remote https://github.com/sveltejs/template**

**! could not find commit hash for HEAD**

.

Can Somebody help me to fix this?

Comment: Looks like degit had internet connection issues, check dns, firewalls, virusscanners, etc

Comment: I have written an answer at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75568479/3608403 It might help you as well.